# Lottie is rendering in low quality my animation, how can I increase the render quality?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, intellij-idea

I'm using Lottie 5.0.3 on Android Studio, i want to add some animations to my layouts, the problem is: When I build the project and install on my phone, i get a very poor quality animation, and I don't understand why, I'm using a json that i was downloaded from Lottie Files, here is my xml is:

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/splash_anim"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:lottie_fileName="hearth_splash.json"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
    />
```

And I play it on Kotlin on this way:

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        var intent:Intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    },2000)
```

I get a very poor quality render, I don't know if can I set the render quality or I'm doing something bad, please help.

Comment: Does setting rendermode helps?
`splashAnim.setRenderMode(RenderMode.HARDWARE)`

Comment: @Quantum_VC Thanks for your answer. I solved increasing the json resolution.

Comment: What attributes did you modify in order to increase the resolution of the animation?